How to automatically configure a ROS 2 lifecycle node in a launch file right after it's initialized?
I am writing a launch file to initialize a lifecycle node, configure it, and activate it. Currently, the node is successfully initialized. I have to manually configure it using ros2 lifecycle set /laserscan_detector_L1 configure. After that, the node is automatically activated by my launch script. I confirmed by commenting out the activation part of code, and then I needed to manually activate.
Below is the part of the launch script about the lifecycle node:
        # Add the laserscan detector node (lifecycle node) for the level
        laserscan_detector_node = LifecycleNode(
            package="rmf_obstacle_detector_laserscan",
            executable="laserscan_detector",
            name=f"laserscan_detector_{level_key}",
            namespace="",
            output="screen",
            parameters=[
                {"level_name": level_key},
            ]
        )
        # When the laserscan_detector node is in unconfigured state, configure it
        laserscan_detector_node_register = launch.actions.RegisterEventHandler(
            launch_ros.event_handlers.OnStateTransition(
                target_lifecycle_node=laserscan_detector_node,
                goal_state="unconfigured",
                entities=[
                    launch.actions.EmitEvent(event=launch_ros.events.lifecycle.ChangeState(
                        lifecycle_node_matcher=launch.events.matches_action(laserscan_detector_node),
                        transition_id=lifecycle_msgs.msg.Transition.TRANSITION_CONFIGURE,
                    )),
                ],
            )
        )
        # When the laserscan_detector node is in Inactive state, activate it
        laserscan_detector_node_activate = launch.actions.RegisterEventHandler(
            launch_ros.event_handlers.OnStateTransition(
                target_lifecycle_node=laserscan_detector_node,
                goal_state="inactive",
                entities=[
                    launch.actions.EmitEvent(event=launch_ros.events.lifecycle.ChangeState(
                        lifecycle_node_matcher=launch.events.matches_action(laserscan_detector_node),
                        transition_id=lifecycle_msgs.msg.Transition.TRANSITION_ACTIVATE,
                    )),
                ],
            )
        )
        # Add the laserscan_detector related actions to launch description
        ld.add_action(laserscan_detector_node)
        ld.add_action(laserscan_detector_node_register)
        ld.add_action(laserscan_detector_node_activate)

I used line 42 to 55 in the example code to write two RegisterEventHandler instances.
Things I have tried:

Change the goal_state to "unknown" or "PRIMARY_STATE_UNKNOWN", but they didn't work. My guess is this goal_state is not the correct one after this node is initialized.
I have also checked the state of the lifecycle node after it's initialized by running ros2 lifecycle get /laserscan_detector_L1. I can confirm it returned unconfigured [1].
Checked the C++ file for the node, but couldn't find the initial state. I also checked the Python file that defines lifecycle node, but I don't see any function definition to get the state of the node. Also checked the Python file for change_state, but that didn't help.


Sorry, my bad, I found what was wrong. Hope this can help someone who works on this in the future.
The configuration works differently from activation for lifecycle nodes. It's not a transition, but a direct initialization of EmitEvent. Instead of the laserscan_detector_node_register definition in the question, I should replace it with:
# Configure the laserscan_detector node after initialization
laserscan_detector_node_configure = launch.actions.EmitEvent(
    event=launch_ros.events.lifecycle.ChangeState(
       lifecycle_node_matcher=launch.events.matches_action(laserscan_detector_node),
       transition_id=lifecycle_msgs.msg.Transition.TRANSITION_CONFIGURE,
    )
)

And change
ld.add_action(laserscan_detector_node_register)

to
ld.add_action(laserscan_detector_node_configure)

